# IIS7 rewrite module: change rules without reset an application

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I use IIS7 rewrite module and all rules are places in a separate config file (not in web.config):

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules configSource="Config\Rewrite.config" />
 </rewrite>
```

Is it possible to changes these rules without reset related application?

Comment: Would a recycle not be ok?

Comment: No, as recycle reset an application